# Pros and cons of passing data via dependency injection vs including it in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, dependency-injection

I'm writing a small non-commercial web app, and I'm wondering how to pass data from one piece of the code to others.  Specifically, I want to output various messages to the user depending on the circumstances ("you're logged in", "logged out", "status updated", etc). (At this point, I don't see the case where I would need to keep several messages in memory, but it's not really relevant.)  So I could structure my code with a `$_SESSION['message']` variable, or I could systematically pass an instance of a `class Message`, or even a string variable, from one php file to the next.

I'm not sure if there are compelling reasons to use one approach rather than the other.

EDIT:  The "pieces of code" I make reference to above are MVC Controllers that decide which function to execute and what to display.  They then redirect to a front controller, so the instance changes.  The front controller then loads the views.

Comment: what are these "pieces of code"? are they running within the same instance or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question makes not much sense to me.

In case you are talking of *different PHP instances* (for example, if you made a redirect after succesful login), you have a little choice but sessions.

In case you are talking of passing messages between code pieces within the same PHP script instance, there is no use for the sessions at all.

Comment: Yes, I do do redirects after the key actions (successful logins, registration, etc) to the front controller.

Comment: Well, after this redirect all your classes are dead and will pass nothing nowhere. Sessions is your only choice here

Answer (score 2):

Passing a Message object would allow you to change how things are implemented without having to adjust every piece of code that uses messages. Using a `$_SESSION` variable directly will tie you to your implementation.

I generally try to avoid using `$_SESSION` directly anywhere in the application, except in the core "boot strapping" procedure. It is a global variable, and those are by nature generally evil.

Comment: Presumably I could include a Message object into the `$_SESSION`...  I have read about the evilness of global variables but I don't understand it perfectly.  In particular, some of the things I've read seem to imply that `$_SESSION` is not as evil as other globals...

Comment: @JDelage none of the PHP superglobals are evil. However, *misuse* of these arrays is evil indeed. Sessions should be used only to preserve a state between HTTP requests. To communicate between modules you have to invent some sort of class messenger

Comment: `$_SESSION` isn't evil in the sense that it's mandatory (in terms of built in features) if you wish to persist data from page to page. The question becomes exactly how you make use of it within your application. Either you "convert" the `$_SESSION` data into application objects at the beginning of the script, or you use them directly throughout the entire application. Direct usage is simpler (and isn't categorically wrong to do), but it can lead to code that is harder to maintain in a large application.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing isn't a dependency injection model, it's a Singleton model (as in, pass a single instance of a class all around). Dependency injection is about passing what you **need** for each **specific** object/function to run, meaning if you have an authentication function for your users, you would need a **database connection**, a **user**, and a **password**. So your code might look like this:

```
function auth($db_conn, $user, $pass) {
```

In your case, for displaying messages to the user, I'd go with the session approach.

Comment: Well in my case I need the message for the pieces of code to work, since one of their function is to decide which message (if any) to display.